# Can't execute Runtime error in depth first search(dfs).Function stops returning

Tags: c++, c++14

```
using namespace std;
bool *marked;
//graph API
class Digraph
{
    int v;
    vector<int>* adj;
    int e;
public:
    Digraph(int V)
    {
        e=0;
        v=V;
        adj=new vector<int>[v];
    }
    void addEdge(int v,int w)
    {
        adj[v].push_back(w);
        e++;
    }
    int V()
    {
        return v;
    }

    vector<int> adjacent(int i)
    {
        return adj[i];
    }
};
//API ends
//this is the problem
void dfs(Digraph g,int s)
{
    marked[s]=true;
    for(int w:g.adjacent(s))
    {
        if(!marked[w])
            dfs(g,w);
    }
}
```

The Dfs here would run perfectly when traversing nodes but when returning it would stop at one node before the last and my program halts.I compiled it on codeblocks ide.
For ex
consider a graph going 1->2->3->4->0->1
when traversing its fine but when returning will stop at vertex 3
Actually i was implementing Cycles in a graph and topological sorts too. but none of them worked, and i have no idea why.

Comment: Please make a [mre] and repot on the things you found out during debugging.

Comment: In `void dfs(Digraph g,int s)` you make copy of Digraph and it just make shale copy of member `vector<int>* adj;` it could be root of your problem.
Rather use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj;` for your multi array.

Comment: Thnak you, For your time I got the problem it was due to `destructors` in my classes they were deleting the `adj` after the first return. Copy constructors solved my problem